# How to double tap to open video feature of camera app?

Tags: camera, video, buttons

I have a clip-on that I sometimes carry my phone in.  When clipped in, it is not possible to interact with the screen. However, I still have access to the buttons on the side, so the double-tap to open the camera is a very useful feature and the volume buttons (either one) can then be used to take one picture or pressing both simultaneously captures a burst.  However, what I would really like to do is to record video, not a still image.  How can I make the double-tap switch to camera *in video mode*?  I can't access my screen, so I can't swipe to select it, so I need the double-tap to go directly there.

I have a Nexus 6P, not rooted, Android 6.0.1.

Comment: If your device is rooted, hardware mapping options may be explored( please mention model, OS and root status in your question). Else you can try [background video recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zenaapps.backgroundvideorecorder2), which can do this- it's a paid app but let's you try short recordings

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, I will take a look at that app.

Comment: If it works for you,ping me so that I can post as an answer. Installed it , was fine but the challenge would be in positioning the cell to grab the video

Comment: @beeshyams I did a preliminary install and it seems to mostly work, but some things are unstable - for instance, it did not respond to my first attempt to stop the video with the volume buttons, the resulting video wouldn't play in the default video player, but it would in a file manager which subsequently hung, etc.  Will experiment more with it later when I have more time and let you know...